# Prevent container from wrapping, make its children wrap instead

Tags: html, css

My layout looks something like this:

```
<div class="left">
    ...
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="inner" />
    ... a bunch of these ...
    <div class="inner" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { display: inline-block; }
.left { width: 25%; }
.right { width: 75%; }
.inner { width: 33%; }
```

I want to do the following:

When the screen is at normal size:

```
+--+-----+
|  |O O O|
|  |O O O|
+--+-----+
```

What I want to happen when I reduce the browser's width:

```
+--+---+
|  |O O|
|  |O O|
|  |O O|
+--+---+
```

What actually happens:

```
+--+
|  |
|  |
+--+
+-----+
|O O O|
|O O O|
+-----+
```

And if I shrink the browser even further: (I also want to avoid this)

```
+--+
|  |
|  |
+--+
+---+
|O O|
|O O|
|O O|
+---+
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3):

This would give you a better result i hope.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}

.inner {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  ...
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="inner" /> ... a bunch of these ...
  <div class="inner" />
</div>
```

Comment: Much less code/work than my flexbox suggestion. This is a good option if you don't need other flexbox features.

Comment: Yes just if he'd like to stick to simple code. Your option would be good too. I'd like to refer him about a tutorial on [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I did the flexbox one but that's a nice answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with flexbox.

**html**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">Some Stuff</div>
  <div class="right">Some other stuff</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.left{
  background-color: red;
}
.right{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

working code pen here https://codepen.io/seekheart/pen/BRNrER